# Write files to azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have an azure function that take some files from storage account and write them inside the function , whene I run locally it works but whene I deply it shows this error

```
Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
```

this coming from a code like this inside the function

```
 with open("./path/Data.csv", "wb") as my_blob:
        blob_data = data.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is might be because of the path as it is read-only. Try using `/tmp` folder instead. In your case you can use `open("/tmp/Data.csv", "wb")`.

You can also refer to this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403985/failure-exception-oserror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-when-using-azurem?msclkid=23af44c8c79d11ecbd0f7dcfd9be1963).

**REFERENCES:**
[Temporary files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#temporary-files)